# Node-Webkit: Application not running by drag drop or running from command line

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

Its my first day with NWjs and I am strugling with it.

I have going through its documentations: [documentations](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/)

I am following whatever is written over there.

1. Downlaoded NWjs and extracted it in a folder
2. Created a sample application
3. Drag drop the `package.json` on `nw.exe`
   [image]

It should show a window however nothing is happening.

I also tried to run it from command line but that did not work too.

```
    "C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\cromium apps\nwjs.exe" "C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\cromium apps\app\package.json"
```

Please guide what should I do.

I am using a windows pc and node.js is also installed.

*Package.json*

```
{
    "name": "helloworld",
    "main": "index.html"
}
```

Comment: And we're talking about the latest version here? 0.14.4?

Comment: @dfb yes it's am using the latest version downloaded from git hub yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 workarounds to run the application but I still do not know why the steps mentioned in documentation did not worked.

So for others I am providing the both workarounds to run the application below:

1. Create a `.zip` of your application folder then rename it `abc.nw` then drag drop it on the `nw.exe` or run the following command in cmd `"path of the nw.exe" "your zip path.nw"`
2. open command line install `nodewebkit` by using the following command `npm install -g nodewebkit` (`npm` must be installed beforehand)
   then cd to your application folder and run the follwoing command `nodewebkit`